# Get (Exception from HRESULT:0x800300002 (STG_E_FILENOTFOUND)) when running a new SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have created two SSRS reports within a Report Project using VS 2019 and they work fine.
When I create a third report using the same procedure and attempt run it I get "Exception from HRESULT:0x800300002 (STG_E_FILENOTFOUND)".
Can someone suggest what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but I had the same issue.

For me, this was caused by Windows Security Ransomware Protection which was preventing **PreviewProcessingService.exe** from running.

You can allow **PreviewProcessingService.exe**, and anything else you don't want blocked, by following these steps.

1. Open **Windows Security** (Just search for Windows Security from the Start Menu)
2. Go to: **Virus & threat protection**, then **Manage ransomware protection**
3. Go to: **Allow an app through controlled folder access**
4. Click on **Add an allowed app** then select **Recently blocked apps**

Also worth noting, I've had multiple services blocked by this (npm, git, etc.). If something isn't working as expected, it's worth checking it it's being blocked.

Hopefully this helps you out.